# Prove fact about polynomial in uncountable fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ideals

$F$-uncountable field.
 $I_{i}$-ideal in $F[x_{1},...,x_{n}]$ 
$F^{n}=\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}V(I_{i})$  
$V(I_{i})\subseteq V(I_{i+1})$ 
Prove that $\exists k, V(I_{k})=F^{n}$ 
All that I've find is that using Hilbert basis theorem we can prove that all ideal are finite generated.

Answer (score 1):

You must note that the statement is not true for countable field $\mathbb Q$. Write $\mathbb Q$ as $\{a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n, \ldots \}$. Then in $\mathbb Q[X]$ define $I_k = (X-a_1)(X-a_2) \ldots (X-a_n)$. Here no $V(I_k)$ is $\mathbb Q$.

Now consider the field is uncountable and $n=1$. Then each $V(I)$ is either empty or finite set or the full space $F$. So the result is clear in this case. So for some $I_k$ we have $V(I_k) = F$ and $I_k =0$.

Comment: ok. it's not problem but it doesn't implies that my statement will be true

Comment: Well case n=1 is obvious but how to reduce k to k-1 to use induction proof?

Comment: I am trying to find it out.

Comment: may be it could help http://mathoverflow.net/questions/73743/countable-union-of-closed-subschemes-over-uncountable-field